# C# Async void of event handler got warning/error

Tags: c#, async-await

[image]

I understand the async should not use `void` as return type unless it is an event handler. But I have code snippet above, when I turn on warning as error in my project setting I got the error above when I compile code.

> RECS0165 Asynchronous method '' should not return void

If I remove `async` then I get another compile error

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda
>   expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async'
>   modifier.

The suggested fix is to add `async` to the anonymous function. It is a dead lock.

Do I do something wrong here?

The steps to reproduce the issue:

- Create a blank UWP project in VS2017, it will create app,xaml and MainPage.Xaml.
- Add following code in in MainPage.Xaml.cs

  namespace App4
  {
      using System;
      using System.Threading.Tasks;
      using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
      using Windows.UI.Core;
      using Windows.UI.Xaml;
      using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

  ```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
  {
      private DispatcherTimer refreshTimer;

      public MainPage()
      {
          this.InitializeComponent();

          this.refreshTimer = new DispatcherTimer()
          {
              Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)
          };

          refreshTimer.Tick += async (sender, e) => { await DisplayMostRecentLocationData(string.Empty); };
      }

      private async Task DisplayMostRecentLocationData(string s)
      {
          await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
          {

          });
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: The delegate is incorrect. `async (sender, e) =>` or use an `EventArg` derived class for `e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue actually comes from Refactoring Essentials.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9b67355-99c8-429f-91d0-65e578b2a7f1/c-async-void-return-type-of-event-handler-got-warningerror?forum=csharpgeneral&prof=required

https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials/issues/280

Answer (score 3):

The `Tick` event handler delegate is incorrect.

Use

```
async (sender, e) => ...
```

or use an `EventArg` derived class for `e`

```
async (object sender, EventArgs e) => ...
```

What you currently have is an anonymous object that you are trying to assign as an event handler. The compiler does not allow that hence the error.

Comment: Changed code to `this.refreshTimer.Tick += async (sender, e) => { await this.DisplayMostRecentLocationData(string.Empty); };` but still same compile error. Or `this.refreshTimer.Tick += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => { await this.DisplayMostRecentLocationData(string.Empty); };` same compile error.

Comment: @hardywang, Given that I do not know what your Display... method does I tested it with `refreshTimer.Tick += async (sender, e) => {
                await Task.Run(() => { });
            };` and `refreshTimer.Tick += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                await Task.Run(() => { });
            };` and it compiles fine.

Comment: the compile error messages are exactly what I quoted in original post. And I also added a complete sample code to demo the issue.